# tsql most effective way to compare three date values in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure.
What is most effective way to compare three date values in where clause?

Example:

```
tbl1.Date1, 
tbl2.Date2, -- NOTE: Date2 can be NULL.
tbl3.Date3
```

Example data:

```
Date1           Date2           Date3
2016-12-20      2016-11-21      2016-11-30
2016-11-21      NULL            2016-12-20
```

First, I compare Date1 and Date2 and I choose "bigger" date.
Then I compare this "bigger" date to Date3.
If comparsion is true, I write values to table.

```
-- This is simplified example:
INSERT INTO records
(
    [user_date],
    [user_name]
)
SELECT 
    tbl1.Date1, 
    tbl1.user_name
FROM 
    table1 AS tbl1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
    INNER JOIN table3 AS tbl3 ON tbl2.id = tbl3.id
WHERE
    -- I need to know what is bigger, Date1 or Date2, so I can compare correct date to Date3.
    ISNULL(tbl2.Date2, tbl1.Date1) <= tbl3.Date3 -- ISNULL, doesn't work here, because Date2 and Date1 can get a value and comparison fails if Date1 is bigger than Date3.
    AND ISNULL(tbl2.Date2, tbl1.Date1) > tbl3.last_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), or [inline if](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), to conditionally return the bigger of the two dates, for comparison.

**Sample Data**

```
-- Sample data.
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Date1   DATE    NOT NULL,
        Date2   DATE    NULL,
        Date3   DATE    NOT NULL
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        Date1,
        Date2,
        Date3
    )
VALUES
    ('2016-01-02', NULL,            '2016-01-01'),  -- D1 > D3.
    ('2015-12-31', '2016-01-02',    '2016-01-01'),  -- D2 > D1 and D3
    ('2015-12-30', '2016-12-31',    '2016-01-01')   -- D3 > D1 and D2
;
```

**Case Expression**

```
-- Using a CASE EXPRESSION.
SELECT
    CASE WHEN s.Date2 > s.Date1 THEN s.Date2 ELSE s.Date1 END AS Bigger_of_D1_D2,
    *
FROM
    @Sample AS s                        
WHERE
    CASE WHEN s.Date2 > s.Date1 THEN s.Date2 ELSE s.Date1 END > s.Date3
;
```

**Inline If (SQL Serer 2012, or above)**

```
-- Using an INLINE IF.
SELECT
    IIF(s.Date2 > s.Date1, s.Date2, s.Date1) AS Bigger_of_D1_D2,
    *
FROM
    @Sample AS s                        
WHERE
    IIF(s.Date2 > s.Date1, s.Date2, s.Date1) > s.Date3
;
```

Both methods rely on the fact that NULL is not equal to anything, inculding itself.  This means that checking D2 against D1 will always return false, if Date2 is null.  If Date1 also allows NULLs this technique would fail.  In that case you could expand the case expression to include more where expressions, or include the ISNULL function.

The second option is an example of [sytactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).  Behind the scenes SQL Server will convert your code into a simple case expression, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks):

> IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE expression.

Comment: In my case IIF was best solution =) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Declare @tbl1 table (id int,date1 date);Insert Into @tbl1 values (1,'2016-12-20'),(2,'2016-11-21 ');
Declare @tbl2 table (id int,date2 date);Insert Into @tbl2 values (1,'2016-11-21'),(2,null);
Declare @tbl3 table (id int,date3 date);Insert Into @tbl3 values (1,'2016-12-30'),(2,'2016-12-20');


Select User_Date = (Select max(d) from (values(date1),(date2),(date3)) D(D))
      ,A.ID
 From  @tbl1 A
 Join  @tbl2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join  @tbl3 C on A.ID=C.ID
```

Returns

```
User_Date   ID
2016-12-30  1
2016-12-20  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
INSERT INTO records
(
    [user_date],
    [user_name]
)
SELECT tbl1.Date1 
      ,tbl1.user_name
FROM  table1 as tbl1
INNER JOIN  table2 as tbl2 on tbl1.ID=tbl2.ID
INNER JOIN  table3 as tbl3 on tbl1.ID=tbl3.ID
WHERE (SELECT CASE WHEN tbl1.Date1 > ISNULL(tbl2.Date2,'1900-01-01') THEN tbl1.Date1 ELSE tbl2.Date2 END) <= tbl3.Date3
      AND 
      (SELECT CASE WHEN tbl1.Date1 > ISNULL(tbl2.Date2,'1900-01-01') THEN tbl1.Date1 ELSE tbl2.Date2 END) > tbl3.last_date
```